# How to debug AML (ACPI) with WinDBG?

Tags: windows, windbg, acpi

I installed Windows Kits and Debugging tools. Also I have ACPI.sys driver installed on my computer. 
I start WinDGB.exe, open executable file and type in windbg.exe command

```
!amli help
```

windbg.exe says that

```
No export amli found
```

Question: how to debug AML code? What should I do to make it work? May be some files are not installed? Or some preferences not done? Or AML debugs not with using windbg?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _"open executable file"_? `!amli` is an extension command in the `acpikd` extension and requires setting up kernel debugging to the target machine.

Comment: By "open executable" I mean "File -> open executable". Ah, thank you about kernel debugging. I tried it, but I got that target machine does not support it. Why is it so?

Comment: In what sense doesn't the target machine support it?